# how do you calculate viscocity from torque arm load cell measurements?

Tags: motors, measurements, torque

I have a piece of company developed equipment that uses a pot mounted on a rotating base plate with a 0.15m torque arm and load cell, a mixing paddle is used to stir the mixture while the controller calculates torque from the motors rpm and force applied to the load cell.

My question is considering a servo viscometer and many other digital viscometers calculate viscocity based upon torque can this be achieved using the setup with what principles would you require?

Comment: Do a search for “torque arm viscosity measurement” - several useful results.